# Using Timber Framework counter with a URL API that continuously counts up

Tags: javascript, html, api, counter

My skills with jquery and such are limited when it comes to this. For our website we are using timber framework with some of the plugins. I would like to use their counter but have the counter go up in real time. Please help if you can. Thank you in advance. in the HTML i have wrote realtime where i would like the counter to be realtime. I hope i have provided enough information. So in summary what i need help with is i would like to use the timber framework style and look but have the counter be realtime instead of stopping at a number and being a very basic counter.

HTML
`

```
                        <div class="column width-4 offset-4 center">
                            <div class="counter-wrapper">
                                <p style="font-size:60px;" class="counter lead"><span class="stats-1" data-count-from="1300000" data-count-to="realtime" >1000000</span></p>
                                <p style="font-size:36px;" class="lead">Hotspots</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

`

Javascript

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready( function(){
        $( '.stats-1' ).counter();
        $( '.stats-2' ).counter({
            autoStart: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Realtime counter URL
https://reelsonar-services.com/api/v1/hotspot_count

OUR COUNTER from a sample site

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flipcountdown.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.flipcountdown.css" />

<script>
    var hotspot_count = 1000000;

    function fetch_waterbody_count() {

        var url="https://reelsonar-services.com/api/v1/hotspot_count";
        //var url="http://reelsonar-services.com:8085/hotspot_count";

        var html = [];
        $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
             $.each(data, function(index, d){
                 html.push("Hotspots: ", d.hotspot_count, "<br>");
                 var count = parseInt( d.hotspot_count );
                 if( count != hotspot_count) {

                     hotspot_count = count;
                     update_counter( hotspot_count )
                 }

             });


        });
    }

    function update_counter( count ) {

        jQuery('#flipcountdown').flipcountdown({size:'md',tick:count});
    }

    function reset_counter( count ) {

        jQuery('#flipcountdown').flipcountdown({size:'md',tick:count});
    }

            function pulse_hotspot() {
        (function pulse(back) {
        $('#hotspot_img').animate(
            {
            'font-size': (back) ? '25px' : '35px',
            opacity: (back) ? 1 : 0.5
            }, 1200, function(){pulse(!back)});
        $('#hotspot_img img').animate(
            {
            'width': (back) ? '125px' : '112px'
            }, 1200);
        })(false);
            }
</script>
```

```
<body style="background: lightblue;text-align: center">
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#fetchButton").click(function(event){

    fetch_waterbody_count();
});

    $("#addOneButton").click(function(event){
    hotspot_count += 1;
    update_counter( hotspot_count );
});

    $("#addTenButton").click(function(event){
    hotspot_count += 10;
    update_counter( hotspot_count );
});

    $("#resetButton").click(function(event){

    reset_counter(1000000);
});

    setInterval(fetch_waterbody_count, 2000);    
    pulse_hotspot();
});

 </script>
 <script>
 jQuery(function(){
 jQuery('#flipcountdown').flipcountdown({size:'md',tick:hotspot_count});  <!-- Medium sized -->
})
</script>

 <div style="font-size: x-large; padding-bottom: 1em">ReelSonar Global Hotspot Counter</div>
 <div style="font-size: large; padding-bottom: 1em">Displays Hotspots as they are created by our users in real time.</div>
```

```
    <pre>(Retrieves Hotspot count every two seconds)</pre>
    <div id="hotspot_img"><img src="hotspot.png" /></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a polling issue: send Ajax request periodically, get the latest number and display it on screen (using Timber's counter to add animation effect).

Here is a working example. Please note it is a bit complex because the returned data is an array, not a single object (need to handle the situation when multiple numbers are returned in one array):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/components/timber.css" />
</head>
<body>

<span data-count-from="1" data-count-to="1" id="counter"></span>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/plugins/jquery.tm.counter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
  $(function() {
    var queue = [];
    var url="https://reelsonar-services.com/api/v1/hotspot_count";
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    var $counter = $(counter);
    var latestNum = null;

    getData(true);
    setInterval(function() {
      getData();
    }, 30000);

    function getData(init) {
      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        if (init) {
          var num = data.shift().hotspot_count;
          counter.dataset.countFrom = num;
          $counter.text(formatNumber(num));
        }
        queue = queue.concat(data);
        playCount();
      });
    }

    function playCount() {
      if (queue.length === 0) {
        return;
      }
      var countTo = queue.shift().hotspot_count;
      if (countTo && countTo === latestNum) {
        playCount();
      }
      latestNum = countTo;

      counter.dataset.countTo = countTo;
      $counter.counter();
      setTimeout(function() {
        counter.dataset.countFrom = countTo;
        if (queue.length > 0) {
          playCount();
        }
      }, 1000);
    }

    function formatNumber( number ) {
      return number.toString().replace( /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,' );
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do this. i really appreciate it. i got it to work with the timber framework. of course my marketing director isnt pleased because it doesnt refresh. i tried explaining to her why. so the problem is getting the ajax to request updates? i'll do some research to see if i can fix that but if you have any solution please let me know. once again thank you so much!!!

Comment: @MikePupo you are welcome. "Content get updated without page refresh" is NOT a problem, it is the main advantage of Ajax. I think what your marketing director need is: get notified when content is updated, otherwise, user won't know the number is changed. To solve this "notify" problem, you can add some animation when number is changed, such as fade-in/fade-out, resize text etc.

Comment: just want to make sure its correct. Right now its displaying the real number of hotspots, but the number is static and doesnt count up or refresh. i've been trying to figure out how to make it refresh and i cannot figure it out.

Comment: sorry i just read your comment, so the counter is not changing at all its just a static number what i need is for the number to change everytime a hotspot is added. this happens about every 10 seconds. if you would like to see it heres a link https://reelsonar.com/pages/test

Comment: If the number need to change every time when a hotspot is added. You can use real-time technology such as WebSocket. Or, you can use simple solution by setting the interval a little bit larger than 10 seconds (such as 11 seconds)

Comment: sorry I wasnt clear. right now the code you provided isnt working. it shows the accurate amount of hotspots but it doesnt count at all. so its just a static number everytime the page is refreshed. it never counts up. what i'd like is for the counter to actually count up when i hotspot is added. So really the code you provided works in a sense that it shows the accurate amount of hotspots at the time of page refresh, but does not count up after that.

Comment: @MikePupo please note there is a `setInterval` in the code, and the number will count up every 30 seconds.